# How to disable the fact that pycharm removes executable permissions from python files

Tags: pycharm

I am working on a python project on pycharm in windows that is automatically deployed to a linux vm. I need the python files to be executable on linux, but whatever I try, pycharm always sets the permissions back to not being executable. I can change the permissions manually on linux but that is a pain.

Git also registers every python file as changed, making me unable to pull changes. If I rollback or stash the changes, the permissions are instantly changed again.

I tried what is suggested [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11920/PyCharm-changes-file-permissions), but the 'safe write' setting no longer exists.

Comment: What is doing the automatic deployment?

Comment: It uploads the files to the linux vm each time I save them.

Comment: Not a `git` question.

Comment: Anyway, changing, _automagically_, the permissions of the files when they are deployed in the linux VM is not an option? Perhaps with a script, I mean.

Comment: I could do that and run all git commands on the linux vm, but I would really prefer to have the pycharm GUI as an option for merge conflicts and such. It would still have pycharm marking the files I have on windows as edited compared to the original permissions commited to git, resulting in errors when I try to pull changes there. I am surprised that I'm not able to configure it to leave the files as they are.